# Geospatial clustering plot with zoom in Python?

Tags: python, clustering, visualization, geospatial

I need to construct an interactive clustering plot. Ideally as the user zooms in the clusters would split-up into smaller clusters at certain zoom levels.

I am planning to have several discrete levels of clustering, and the plot would visualise each depending on the zoom-level the user is at.

I'm not that sure how to approach this. Are there any python packages that can help?

Any advice appreciated.

Comment: Interested in a non-Python answer?

Answer (score 0):

I sorted this using a Jupyter package called ipyleaflet, which is a python plugin to the javascript mapping library leaflet.

You can add/remove layers from the map while the widget is running, which is exactly what I needed.

Comment: It would be great if you can also give a sample example.